# R web-scraping remove unnecessary lines

Tags: r

I am trying to webscrape a table which is intermittently interrupted by a repeat of the title header:
date    LME Tin Cash-Settlement LME Tin 3-month LME Tin stock

I can generate a list containing the data

```
library(XML)
tableSN <-readHTMLTable("http://www.westmetall.com/en/markdaten.php?     action=show_table&field=LME_Sn_cash",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
tableSN


class(tableSN)
```

But how can I get rid of the repeating title header to generate a clean datatable showing just the dates and the number columns

How can I convert the numbers (eg 21.720,00  to 21,720.00) and the date (eg 30. December 2013 to 30-12-2013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working from the data.frame object `dd` of @agstudy's answer, you could do

```
for(i in 2:4) {
  dd[,i] <- gsub("\\.", "", dd[,i])
  dd[,i] <- gsub(",", ".", dd[,i])
  dd[,i] <- as.numeric(dd[,i])
}

lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
dd[,1] <- gsub("Febuary", "February", dd[,1])
dd[,1] <- as.Date(strptime(dd[,1], "%d. %B %Y"))
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", lct)
str(dd)
```

which should convert the numbers and the date.

Answer (score 2):

You get a list , you can transform it a data.frame like this :

```
dd = do.call(rbind,tableSN)
dd = dd[-grep('date',dd$date),]
```